# NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames() returns empty array

Tags: swift

I'm writing a unit test around some code that will eventually display a list of timezones.  But in my test, when running on my IPod Touch, the method NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames() returns back an array with 0 values in it.

Code is pretty simple:

```
func testTimeZones(){
    var tzlist = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames() 
    XCTAssertGreaterThan(tzlist.count, 0, "TimeZone list empty")
}
```

Comment: Is your iPod connected to the Internet?  Has it ever been?

Comment: it is on the internet, no issues there.